# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless problem but Windows can work

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I am a student. My laptop has both windows7 and ubuntu 12.10. In school, with school wifi, both OS are working well.

But in the hostel, with hostel wifi, Ubuntu only works for about 4 to 5 min and although it appear connected, the webpage does not load. ping google appear 5-digit. I switch to windows and it works.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the hostel wifi network, not with your laptop...

Comment: ya i know.. but windows can access internet quite fast.. why ubuntu cannot..

Answer (score 0):

Just  click on your network icon from top right and click on the network name which gets disconnected. I used to face and still face this problem. Actually clicking on your network name refreshes the network and hope it will start working again in your case...

Note : Its working for me.

Comment: It used to work for me in Win7, refreshing the network. but I tried refreshing and it just doesn't work.. still Thanks.

Comment: Click on the network name from the menu bar from top right corner and it will refresh the network.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your network when you get home.

If it does not work, deactivate your wireless network then try adding it again. If you recently installed a new software, you may as well try uninstalling it and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I even tried reboot.. it doesn't work. the wireless dies after a while.. or from the start. i try reinstall ubuntu the problem persists.