# wireless does not work

Tags: 12.10, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.10 wireless problem but Windows can work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247406/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-problem-but-windows-can-work)

I am a student. My laptop has both windows7 and ubuntu 12.10. In school, with school wifi, both OS are working well.

But in the hostel, with hostel wifi, Ubuntu only works for about 4 to 5 min and although it appear connected, the webpage does not load. ping google appear 5-digit. I switch to windows and it works.

I know some may think that there is some problem with hostel network. Yes. There is. But windows can work.. and I really want to use my ubuntu..

Is there any suggestion?